# GNU make - depend only on file existence and not modification time

Tags: linux, build, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I want to have a makefile in which I have a task a that can only run if a file `b` exists, but does not need to be re-run if `b` is updated. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define order-only prerequisites.

Note that this is not necessarily supported by all versions of make.

Comment: Clearmake (the clearcase make) does not support the "order-only-prerequisites", but that probably is not going to disturb @tohava. Anyways, i just ran into troubles when using clearmake long time ago .

Comment: @chatraed The question was tagged with `gnu-make` or I would have added that caveat to the answer but it is handy to point out nonetheless.